# How do I access the data in this array in Swift, which is passed from PHP?

Tags: php, ios, arrays, swift

I am having trouble accessing the contents of `Form` within this array:

```
["leagueStats": {
Form =     (
            (
                    {
            date = "2017-01-31";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 42;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-26";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 41;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-24";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = D;
            "results_id" = 37;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-21";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 34;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-21";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 35;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-07";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 27;
        },
                    {
            date = "2016-12-30";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 24;
        },
                    {
            date = "2016-12-24";
            "player1_name" = Dicky;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 21;
        }
    ),
            (
                    {
            date = "2017-01-25";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = D;
            "results_id" = 40;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-25";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 39;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-25";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 38;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-24";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = D;
            "results_id" = 37;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-24";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 36;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-21";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 35;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-21";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 34;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-21";
            "player1_name" = G;
            "player1_result" = D;
            "results_id" = 33;
        }
    ),
            (
                    {
            date = "2017-01-31";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 42;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-26";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = W;
            "results_id" = 41;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-25";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 38;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-25";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = D;
            "results_id" = 40;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-25";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 39;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-24";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 36;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-21";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = D;
            "results_id" = 33;
        },
                    {
            date = "2017-01-15";
            "player1_name" = Sultan;
            "player1_result" = L;
            "results_id" = 30;
        }
    )
);
]
```

This is my code:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.xyz.uk/xyz/getLeagueStats.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "player_id=\(self.playerId2!)&community_id=\(communityId2!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                    if let dict = json?["leagueStats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        print ("step 1")

                        if let arr = dict["Form"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {

                        print ("step 2")

                            self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0 as! [String : String]) }
                            print (self.leagueForm)
                            print (self.leagueForm.count)

                            for i in 0..<self.leagueForm.count {
                                let form = self.leagueForm[i]
                                print (form.player_results!)
                                self.formGuide.append(form.player_results!)

                            }

                            print ("now")
                            print (self.formGuide)
                            self.resultsDisplay.results = self.formGuide
                            self.resultsDisplay.results = self.resultsDisplay.results.reversed()
                            self.resultsDisplay.displayResults()

                        }

}
```

The array `Form` is within the array `leagueStats` because `leagueStats` also carries other arrays from a PHP API call.

There should be 3 array within `Form`, results data for; Dicky,G,Sultan.

Where am I going wrong in not being able to access this data?

I'm not sure if it is required but here is my PHP script which deals with this call:

```
$communityPlayersIds = array();
$communityPlayersIds = $dao->getSpecificCommunity($communityId);
foreach ($communityPlayersIds as $cPI){
    $playerForm[] = $dao->getCommunityForm($cPI, $communityId);
    $i++;
}
$Form = array('playerForm' => $playerForm);
$arr = array('Form' => $playerForm);
echo json_encode (array('leagueStats' => $arr));
```

The output at the top of this post is from `print(json!)`.

I am getting as far as printing out 'step1', but the code is failing at that point as 'step2' is not printing.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to evaluate all 24 dictionary objects to understand what’s wrong.  Pare your data down so it’s easier to understand the format it’s really in.  This is essentially what you have:

```
["leagueStats": {
Form =     (
        (
                {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        "player1_name" = Dicky;
        "player1_result" = L;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },
                {
        date = "2016-12-24";
        "player1_name" = Dicky;
        "player1_result" = W;
        "results_id" = 21;
    }
),
        (
                {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        "player1_name" = Sultan;
        "player1_result" = W;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },
                {
        date = "2017-01-15";
        "player1_name" = Sultan;
        "player1_result" = L;
        "results_id" = 30;
    }
)
);
]
```

So really you have:

```
key : {
  key : {
     [dictionary, dictionary], 
     [dictionary, dictionary]
  }
}
```

Edit:

```
if let arr = dict["Form"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Indicates that the value for 'Form' should be an array of dictionaries.  You have an array of arrays of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks Frankie, could you please expand with some instructions on what I need to do as I am fairly new to Swift so don't fully understand what you are telling me to do.  Cheers